# Which way of accessing C++ enumerators is better?

Tags: c++, enums

I'm looking for some best practice advice. If you have a class declared in C++ like so:

```
class Foo {
public:
    enum { A, B, MAX};
};
```

Should the enum be accessed like:

```
Foo::A
```

or

```
Foo *var; 
var->A;
```

Up until today I had always accessed the constant values like `Foo::A`, rather than through a ptr of the class type. In truth I didn't even believe it was possible. Has anyone come across when and if each form should be used or should I stick to the tried and tested `Foo::A` method?

EDIT: made Foo var into Foo *var it was a typo as most people have spotted thanks.

Comment: The second syntax should not compile: it should be either `Foo *var`, or `var.A`.

Comment: Wow, didn't realize the enum could be accessed as `var.A`.  I've always used `Foo::A`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The enum is associated with the class, rather than with instances.  So `Foo::A` is better.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, your example is supposed to either declare a pointer `Foo * var` or access the enumerator as `var.A`.

If you don't have an object or pointer available, then obviously the "class" form `Foo::A` is the only sensible option.

If you do, then both forms are equivalent. In my opinion, the "class" form is more expressive since it matches the association with the class rather than the object. It might also save arguments with people who don't believe that it's valid.

In some circumstances (e.g. within a template, or with an object declared with `auto` type) the class name may be complicated or even unknown, in which case the "object" form would be better:

```
template <typename T>
void f()
{
    typename some::complicated::type::depending_on<T>::type var;
    var.thing = var.A;            // OK
    var.thing = decltype(var)::A; // Ugly, requires C++11
    var.thing = some::complicated::type::depending_on<T>::type::A; // Yuck!
}
```

Comment: Hi Mike. Interesting point about templates. Although, the enum members are never going to be type parametric anyway, so it makes more sense to put them in a common base class that isn't itself caught up in the crazy type mangling.

Answer (score 1):

First version is better, like @KevinA.Naude said. If you're looking for a way to have scope for your `enum`, you may want to check out the C++11 `enum class`, which allows you to have constructs like `enum class X {A, B, MAX};` which enforce the scope - you will need `X::A` to reference the internals of it.